# How to pass parameter from javascript to C# method in windows phone hybrid application

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am creating a hybrid windows phone application in which I need to pass parameter from javascript function in html to c# method through `script.notify`

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body onload="junk('hello')">
    <script>
        function junk(name) {
            window.external.notify("Hello " + name);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My question is how to get this particular method's  parameter  `junk()`  in C#**

If I use below code , I am receiving all the parameters from all the methods but I need parameters from `junk()` method alone

```
void webBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but I need parameters from `junk()` method alone"?

Comment: If I am using more than one method with parameters , I will receive all of them in webBrowser_ScriptNotify()  message box In that situation how will I get it from junk() alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive all script notifications (from all methods) from within the WebBrowser control, because your event handler `webBrowser_ScriptNotify` is linked to that WebBrowser:

A code example taken from [Matthias Shapiro's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthiasshapiro/archive/2013/02/15/getting-started-with-windows-phone-8-html5-apps.aspx) *(though you're already doing this, but it's missing from your information above)*

---

> We can tell our app to handle that script launch either in the XAML of our WebBrowser:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" ScriptNotify="HTML_Script_Launched" />
```

> Or by assigning it in the xaml.cs file

```
Browser.ScriptNotify += HTML_Script_Launched;
```

---

<sup>Ofcourse your handler is called 'webBrowser_ScriptNotify' instread of 'HTML_Script_Launched'.</sup>

So in `webBrowser_ScriptNotify` you will have to determine from which method/source the `window.external.notify` was done.

Maybe the `NotifyEventArgs e` object contains additional information? <sup>(I haven't looked into this myself)</sup>

Or you can define your own format to send both the message (from the junk() method in this case) and details about where it came from; a sort of "meta data" if you will.